# Are Document DB Triggers executed in parallel?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are trying to use document DB trigger to generate autonumbers. For this purpose we have a special document in our collection to store the auto number and then every other document in the collection is created by calling this trigger. The trigger behaves in the following manner -

1) Reads the last used number from the autonumber document.
2) Increments the number by 1 and then saves the incremented value back to the autonumber document 
3) Creates a new document with an autoId field set to the incremented value and rest of the field of  the new document are as passed into the body

```
await documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync("collectionURI", newDocument, new RequestOptions() { PreTriggerInclude = new List<string> {"autoNumbersTrigger"} });
```

We tested this while running the document DB client locally on our machines and even with 100K parallel inserts, our trigger never ran into a concurrency problem. Hence the question, is this behavior guaranteed? Is it safe to say that the described triggered behavior will never run into concurrency issues?

Comment: What consistency level do you have set for your collection?

Comment: strong consistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch `(int)DocumentClientException.StatusCode == 449` (retry with), which can be returned during a concurrent updates to the same document. As you've noticed, this is rare even at high write rates.

Comment: Ok, can I requeue the operation after catching that exception? Could you please elaborate on the best practices for retrying the trigger operation after catching this exception?

Comment: Yes, you can resubmit. Since triggers are transactional, on errors they get automatically rolled back, and can be safely retried any number of times.